# Open URL in different ViewController when tableView cell is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController for a slide-out menu in my app. The main View Controller contains a WKWebView to open URLs. When the slide-out button is pressed, a table view Controller appears.

I want to have the name of a website displayed in a Table View Cell in the Table View Controller in the slide-out menu and open that website in the WKWebView in the main View Controller when the cell is pressed.

This may seem like an easy question, but I can't seem to find anything about it online.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember the implementation of SWRevealViewController, it uses the `static table view`.

If you are okay with the `static table view` that will have your links then you may just create a `delegate` method that will be called based on the cell that was chosen on the Table `View Controller`. This delegate will notify your `ViewController` and say which link to open.

Hope it's clear. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I’m new to table view, so I’m not sure of the different types. However, I made a sample project where table view cells were populated from an array, so I was going to create an array with a few different websites and populate the table view from that. For example, I could have an array [facebook.com,Twitter.com] and set cell 0 and 1 equal to the values in the array. I could then create the url, but where I am stuck is opening the url in the other view controller with the wkwebview. Could you please explain how I could pass the url to the other view controller?

Comment: @ScottB. please check the delegate pattern. As said, it will help you. There are really a lot of tutorials on that. They are much better than me writing quick code here for you. The main idea is that you need to notify from your Table ViewController to the Second View Controller about the cell that was tapped. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In SideMenuViewController (view controller in which you have table with links)

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let mainViewController  = MainViewController()
mainViewController.link = linksArray[indexPath.row]
self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(mainViewController, animated: true)

}
```

1. init new main view controller that have WKWebView
2. pass link as a property
3. set that view controller as new front view controller